# some of the keys in my keyboard are not working correctly

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-14.04, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using ubuntu 14.04. Suddenly I could notice that some of my keys in keyboard are not working correctly. When I press space bar it prints comma and other keys also behave abnormally by printing different characters.

The keyboard layout which I am using is English-US. I could find that it is dead.

Because of this issue I couldn't even use Open-office writer.

So I tried the following steps as explained in the links.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/68051/some-characters-like-quotes-only-appear-after-pressing-spacebar-how-to-change-t

https://askubuntu.com/questions/69306/tilde-and-double-quote-keys-dont-work-on-the-command-line

But still the issue exists. I want to know whether it is hardware or software issue or symptoms of any virus attack and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 4):

It happened to me before. In my case, keys were not loaded properly during installation. Open the terminal and type the following:

```
sudo loadkeys us
```

I hope this helps!